# how can i upload and image and 2 textView data in android studio using volley and php?

Tags: java, php, mysql, upload, android-volley

i have created an app for uploading images and text, using volley and php. Here the upload.php

```
include_once "koneksi.php"; 
class emp{}

$image = $_POST['image'];
$name = $_POST['name'];

//ini kode yang saya tambah yaitu item
$item = $_POST['item']

if (empty($name)) { 
    $response = new emp();
    $response->success = 0;
    $response->message = "Please dont empty Name."; 
    die(json_encode($response));
} else {
    $random = random_word(20);

    $path = "images/".$random.".png";

    // sesuiakan ip address laptop/pc atau URL server
    $actualpath = "http://192.168.43.137/android/upload_image/$path";

    // saya tambah variabel item
    $query = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO volley_upload (photo,name,item) VALUES ($actualpath','$name','$item')");

    if ($query){
        file_put_contents($path,base64_decode($image));

        $response = new emp();
        $response->success = 1;
        $response->message = "Successfully Uploaded";
        die(json_encode($response));
    } else{ 
        $response = new emp();
        $response->success = 0;
        $response->message = "Error Upload image";
        die(json_encode($response)); 
    }
}   

// fungsi random string pada gambar untuk menghindari nama file yang sama
function random_word($id = 20){
    $pool = '1234567890abcdefghijkmnpqrstuvwxyz';

    $word = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $id; $i++){
        $word .= substr($pool, mt_rand(0, strlen($pool) -1), 1);
    }
    return $word; 
}

mysqli_close($con);
```

?>

Also for its .xml part I use Fab for image upload button and 2 TextView ie editItem and editText. I also added imageView to the image to be uploaded. Before I added textView editItem items in XML and JAVA, the application went perfectly, but after I decided to add one more textView to upload (so there are 2 textviews in total), the data was not successfully sent to the database, whereas previously uploaded 1 image and 1 textView description, but my goal is to upload 1 picture and 2 textView description and it failed uploaded 1 image and 2 textView (editText, editItem)

how do i fix this? I want to upload 1 image and 2 textView (editText, editItem)

MainActivity.java = https://drive.google.com/open?id=1uxKxGmpRoPOJiKFLkXxGMxYrMgxBO3se
activity_main.xml = https://drive.google.com/open?id=1xPso2Z_s0CV078UBUIzX1jjpfMG9k9_2

[this is the logcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksA6r.png)

Comment: Where is your upload command with php?

Comment: i think you must read my MainActivity.java and i suggest you to read my upload.php

Answer (score 0):

According to logcat logs the php part is incorrect.

```
$item = $_POST['item']; // <--- You should put a comma at the end.
```

Comment: If your problem is solved, select the answer and close the question.I thank you for making your return.